# Checking Username Availability while the user is typing iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Like the title explained well, I'm looking to check if user exist in parse.com while the user is typing. I came out so far with this code from their documentation but if you have better suggestion

```
let userName = userNameTextField.text
let query = PFUser.query()
query!.whereKey("Username", equalTo:"%userName%")
let usernames = query!.findObjects()
if usernames != nil { print("existing")} else {print("notexisting")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example for you:

```
// First get user's inputted text
let enteredUserName = userNameTextField.text

// Then query and compare
var query = PFQuery(className: "User")
query.whereKey("yourUsers", equalTo: enteredUserName)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
    if error == nil {
        if (objects!.count > 0){
            isTaken = true
            println("username is taken")
        } else {
            println("Username is available. ")
        }
    } else {
        println("error")
    }
}
```

From [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688945/swift-parse-check-if-username-is-taken) post.

Comment: I add in your query istaken... but it's still not working I have always the same answer available even in parse the username is existing ...

Comment: I found it ! your have to update  (className: "_User") by  (className: "_User") ! but what does mean "_" ?

Comment: But how to show for the user if the user is taken while the user is typing how to add that in my code ?

Comment: You can use delegate methods of textField.

Comment: Can you be more specific please with an example  thanks !

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394933/how-do-i-check-when-a-text-field-changes-in-swift

Comment: so from what I understand I have to add this code ?   but where ? textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    
    func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        //mycode
    }

Comment: Follow this tutorial: http://sourcefreeze.com/uitextfield-and-uitextfield-delegate-in-swift/

Comment: thanks ! but I'm stack how to populate the UILabel with my print() while i'm typing ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: Feel free to ask another question with more detail.. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165441/how-to-populate-my-uilabel-from-my-uitext-while-im-typing-with-spinning-icon@DharmeshKheni