# how can I change my UIlabel live while I'm typing in UItextfield? with spinning icon

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

how can I change my UIlabel live while I'm typing in UItextfield? with spinning icon

I cam out with this code so far below with adding the class UITextFieldDelegate, but i'm still stuck on how how to populate the UILabel and having a spinning time with my print() while i'm typing

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // First get user's inputted text
    let enteredUserName = userNameTextField.text

    //bool to see if username is taken
    var isTaken: Bool = false

    // Then query and compare
    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: enteredUserName!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
        if error == nil {
            if (objects!.count > 0){
                isTaken = true
                print("username is taken")
            } else {
                print("Username is available. ")
            }
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify your post. The entire question should be in the body, not rely on someone having taken notice of the title. What does "user is taken" mean? Clarify as much as possible. Pretend no-one else knows what you are trying to do, so explain everything.

Comment: what about now ? @BillWoodger

Comment: Better, but the question itself should be in the body of the post. The title is not supposed to be the question, or the only place the question is.

Comment: Can you help me with my question ?

Comment: No, I know nothing of the area you are working in. I just came across the question in passing. Apparently one person likes your question, as they have somehow upvoted it, but I think you need to make the question much clearer. Try talking it through with a colleague or friend who knows nothing about it, so that you can formulate a question they can understand, even if they can't directly help.

Comment: my question is clear now :)

Answer (score -1):

To update a label upon a change in a text field you can do this. In `viewDidLoad()`, register your text field for a value change event:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
```

And create a function which this event calls:

```
func textFieldDidChange() {
    label.text = textField.text
}
```

This is done with outlets for your `UILabel` and `UITextField` called `label` and `textField` respectively.

For the spinning icon while editing you can make use of the `UITextFieldDelegate` by setting the text field as a delegate and also an activity indicator that uses the following functions to detect whether the text field is active or not:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: I had an error with textFieldDidChange, Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: '-[XXX.userNameViewController textFieldDidChange]: unrecognized selector sent to instance